# HUGO URL rewritting with .htaccess

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, hugo

I have an URL where Hugo's static build sites are:

www.myurl.com/blog

For example the index.md/index.html from Hugo is accessed like

www.myurl.com/blog/index.html

Now I need htaccess to rewrite the URL to be:

www.myurl.com/index.html

How do I do that?

In the meantime I tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works, but not exactly like I want it to. Because if I have something linked in a blogpost which is in www.myurl.com/somwhere/really/deep/detail.html , it won't work, because it redirects to /blog/. Anything to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule will redirect all none /blog/ urls to blog. But you can filter out all directories you want to exclude from this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somewhere
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somewhere2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Am I blind or would this redirect stuff to somewhere somewhere2 too? I cannot test it until next week, since I'm currently on the road with no access to my server.

Comment: Can't seem to get it working. All non /blog/ are reroutet to /blog/, except I also added ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gudshite```, and yet when I go to /gudshite/ I still land on /blog/.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`aliases`](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#aliases) in your front matter.

For example, in your `blog/index.md`:

TOML

```
+++
aliases = [
    "/index.html",
]
+++
```

YAML

```
---
aliases:
    - "/index.html"
---
```